# How to create a web-based PHP that can print to multiple printer(when idle) using silent printing

Tags: desktop-printer, printer-building

The print job connect to the database. When there is an idle printer, the print job directly goes to it. It need to connect with print server too. 
How do i start? Can someone help me...
Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Adia. You question is very broad in it's current state, as often is the case when you don't know where to start looking for answers. It seems, however, that you are looking for a way to set up an *automated printer farm*. You might want to focus your question on that.

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/Hoektronics/BotQueue   ?

Comment: @Aida_athny, I am flagging this question for being *too broad*, which could lead to it being closed. You may choose to edit your question to become more specific, and then ask for it to be reopened, should this happen. Please have a look at the following link for a general guidance on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with connecting your printer(s) to OctoPi. From there, try to find either an API or way to create your own plugin. Then just set up a workstation that will manage your print queue and delegate the prints using some form of web request.

I personally don't recommend creating your own slicing engine. If you want to do everything directly from "the workstation" try looking into Skeinforge (most popular from ReplicatorG slicer), Cura (I believe from Ultimaker), and/or Miracle Grue (from MakerWare) as your slicing engine. You can most documentation/source on GitHub.

In the meantime, try to narrow down the general sense of **how** you want to accomplish this and edit your question. As a reminder for more technical questions regarding code, please use Stack Overflow. For example, "How to create/use REST request?"

Comment: +1 for mentioning OctoPi! From the rather vague question, that is a much more relevant solution than just saying "learn programming, then do this or that" in general. :)